# Isotope JS jumpy

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have the following situation with my site

http://codepen.io/tgreen/full/PzAYWv/

which has a group of divs for isotope to work on followed by a div.

`<div class="grid"> // isotope grid items
   <div of all items>
 </div>
 <div square /> // random div after items`

Now running the code you can see that the div square jumps as isotope changes with a smooth transition. For some reason this problem was not happening with is 1.5.25. I would like the smooth transition to be applied to all my page elements as they adjust in height.

Answer (score 0):

I asked question on github and got the answer. You need to add a transition time for height in css for your containing element.

```
.grid {
   transition: height 0.4s;
}
```

That will do it.